# Is IEnumerable<T> an Interface or a Collection?

Tags: c#

As far as I understand, Interfaces are contracts that implementers must follow. But in that case :

```
IEnumerable<int> numQuery = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

IEnumerable is used as a collection type doesn't it ? Why not doing something like this ?

```
public class EnumCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
}
EnumCollection<T> numQuery = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

I think I've missed something...

Comment: No, it's used as an interface. It's the type of `numQuery` *variable*, not the object accessed through it

Comment: `Where()` / `OrderBy()` return `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can use that as the type for `numQuery`

Comment: interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What is `EnumCollection` in your question? Seems a very empty class to me.

Comment: The whole point of interfaces is that you don't need to know details about the implementing class and that's the case here with Linq where all you need to know is that you can iterate the values.  Underneath there might be a collection or just code that generates values, but that's the detail that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 17):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface that represents a *sequence*. Now; collections can usually *be used* as sequences (so... `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`), but the reverse is not necessarily true. In fact, it isn't strictly required that you can even iterate a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) more than once.

Many LINQ operations *check* whether the sequence you're working with is *also* a collection (`IList<T>` etc), in order to provide optimized implementations (`.Count` rather than counting by iterating, etc).

The result of `.Where(...)` etc is just: a sequence. It isn't cast back to an `EnumCollection<T>` just because you started with an `EnumCollection<T>`. In the case of `.Where`, the data isn't even stored anywhere - it is a filter that applies the condition *while enumerating*. Meaning: when you try to fetch the next item, it simply iterates the inner sequence, discarding the items that don't match. In the case of `OrderBy` it *is* buffered (by necessity - in the general case, it is impossible to sort without buffering), but: that's an implementation detail that you aren't usually exposed to.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 6):

`IEnumerable` is definitely an interface.

`Where` and `OrderBy` are *extension methods* provided by System.Linq that act against the interface. Each collection class implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the interfaces is that you want a class that uses the collection to depend only on the specific methods that it really needs to.

The reason you wouldn't want them to access other methods on the full class is because you may want to change the underlying implementation being used **without changing the classes that use it**.

For example, if you wanted used the EnumCollection in your other classes, then you'd be tied to that implementation explicitly.  Whereas, if you used the interface in the using classes, you could swap the implementation of EnumCollection to say a StringCollection, and your classes would still work because they only needed the IEnumerable interface.

This stems from the I in SOLID.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Notice how the List class has many MANY interfaces;

```
[Serializable]
public class List<T> : System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>, System.Collections.IList
```

... and that the HashSet class shares some of them...

```
[Serializable]
public class HashSet<T> : System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>, System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>, System.Runtime.Serialization.IDeserializationCallback, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @InBetween Didn't mean from a security point of view, only from a "keep it abstracted" point of view.  The abstraction of the interface allows the implementation to change without the need to change your class.  You could then easily use a HashSet, List, Whatever.  I certainly could have worded this better though...

Comment: @InBetween I think I need to be clearer in that the reason you don't want those methods exposed is because you want to protect yourself from future changes.  Not because you're hiding things you'd rather were hidden.  I'll try to get the wording right